# How to make a large number of files in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

My goal is to make a chosen amount of small .txt files.
My current script is very basic:

```py
file=open("1234.txt","w")
file.write("This is my file")
file.close()
```

I think I have to do something like this but I get invalid syntax errors.

```py
name=file.txt()
filename=name+1()
file=open(file,"w")
file.write("this is my file")
```

It needs to make a chosen amount of files that are called practically the same thing because I can mass edit them after.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "*infinitely*"? You want to create an "*infinite*" number of files?

Comment: I want to know how to. Mainly I'm just trying to learn more about python. I think a script that fills up a hardrive with .txt could be interesting. I'm then going to make one that deletes them all (:

Comment: what I'm really trying to do is make it create one file called anything that says Hello World. Then it makes more named anything1 anything2.... you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    file_name = f"file{i}.txt"
    file = open(file_name, "w")
    file.write("This is my file")
    file.close()
```

Comment: Is this answer sensible? Probably it raises more questions to the OP than it answers (f-string, range). OP should read an introduction to python, that's beyond the scope of any answer.

Comment: @pasbi I've always learned things by seeing how other people did them and then figuring out how it works by tinkering with it. I think any explanation would make it more unclear and would take away from the learning experience

Comment: The approach you describe requires the willingness to research, read and experiment. However, the style of the question and comments implies the OP is not willing to do this. Look at the discussion under QuantumChris' answer and see that it does not work. No offense, but I don't think the OP's "question" can be answered well in the context of this site.

Comment: @pasbi after reading that exchange, I completely agree with you.

Comment: I was very tired when I wrote the question and the responses. I have been trying to figure out how to do loads of different codes for hours myself and it hasnt been working. I use the answers I get on here and I figure out how to implement them further. I am willing to research, read and expirement and that is why I am doing this practically

Comment: useless (at least to me) code just to learn how to do that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,100):
     filename = f"file{i}.txt"
     with open(filename, "w") as file:
          file.write("my file")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, just use a for-loop?

```py
MAX_NUM_OF_FILES = 10
for file_num in range(MAX_NUM_OF_FILES):
    with open(f'my_file_{file_num}.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(f'This is file number {file_num}')
```

Comment: yes but do i make it actually amke the ten differently named files

Comment: The files will be named `"my_file_0"`, `"my_file_1"` ... etc

Comment: says invalid syntax

Comment: If you're using python version <3.6 then f strings will not work. Try replacing them with `.format()` or `%s` style [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).

Comment: What specifically does not work? If you want help you need to put more effort into asking for it or people will not bother.

Comment: Ok sorry I have to go but when I come back I will try and explain well.